# Java Spring will not talk to Consul when run as a Docker container

Tags: java, docker, spring-cloud, microservices, consul

I am trying to solve what I believe is a common use case for running micro services.  In this case I am testing consul with a spring cloud application. I am trying to test consul in two different ways.  The first of which is running in a docker container and the other is running on the docker host machine.  I am then attempting to start a spring cloud container that will talk with either consul example.

I have been unable to make the spring cloud application talk to consul when the spring cloud application is run as a docker container.  When the spring cloud application is run with the host networking mode it works as it can resolve the localhost ports, but this is not an acceptable solution if I wish to run multiple instances of the image.

An example of my docker compose file when running both services as containers is shown below. Here I am attempting to set the consul uri in spring cloud through the environment variables, but have been unable to get it to work using a variety of configurations.  If anyone could point to an example of these functions working together that would be immensely helpful.

```
 consul1:
  image: progrium/consul
  ports:
    - "8400:8400"
    - "8500:8500"
    - "8600:53/udp"
    - "8600:53/tcp"
  environment:
      GOMAXPROCS: 100
      entrypoint: "/bin/consul"
      hostname: consul
      command: agent -log-level=debug -server -config-dir=/config -bootstrap -ui-dir /ui

simpletest:
    build: simpletest
    hostname: simpletest
    environment:  
      JAVA_OPTS: "-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,suspend=n -Dspring.cloud.consul.host=consul1"
    ports:
     - 39041:7051
     - 39052:7055
#     d2fdockerroot_consul1_1 consul
#    links:
#     - consul1
```

Comment: That should work once you enable the `links: - consul1` part since that results in an entry in `/etc/hosts`  of the simpletest container so it resolves `consul1` hostname to the docker-internal ip of the consul1 container. You can test that individually, maybe your JAVA_OPTS aren't used (by some script to set those parameters)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you have an example of a brewery system - https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/brewery. One of the files is a docker-compose file for CONSUL.

https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/brewery/blob/master/docker-compose-CONSUL.yml

Check out all the `application-consul.yaml` files that are inside the codebase to see how to set up the Spring Boot apps to talk to consul.

Example: https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/brewery/blob/master/aggregating/src/main/resources/application-consul.yaml

In case of any issues write here or go to spring-cloud gitter https://gitter.im/spring-cloud/spring-cloud

Comment: That was extremely useful.  Using that I was able to modify my example to specify the consul url by setting  under environment "spring.cloud.consul.host: discovery" which apparently is enough for this instance.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem: linking to my consul container was not enough. However, the following did it for me: As stated [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-consul/), the corresponding consul host and port configuration needs to be placed in `bootstrap.yml`, not `application.yml`.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    consul:
      host: consul
      port: 8500
```

with the corresponding `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "2.0"

services:
  consul:
    image: consul:latest
    ports:
      - "8500:8500"
my-service:
    build: path/to/dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - consul
    links:
      - consul:consul
```

Comment: Thanks! Was facing the same issue, adding the bootstrap.yml solved my problem.